# Mock UserDefaults Object In Unit Test Returning _ArrayBuffer

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, swift3, mocking

I'm trying to remove dependencies to OS objects like URLSessions and UserDefaults in my unit tests. I am stuck trying to mock pre-cached data into my mock UserDefaults object that I made for testing purposes.

I made a test class that has an encode and decode function and stores mock data in a member variable which is a [String: AnyObject] dictionary. In my app, on launch it will check the cache for data and if it finds any, a network call is skipped.

All I've been able to get are nil's or this one persistent error:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

Looking at the debugger, the decoder should have return an array of custom type "Question". Instead I get an _ArrayBuffer object.

What's also weird is if my app loads data into my mock userdefaults object, it works fine, but when I hardcode objects into it, I get this error.

Here is my code for the mock UserDefaults object:

```
class MockUserSettings: DataArchive {
    private var archive: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

    func decode<T>(key: String, returnClass: T.Type, callback: (([T]?) -> Void)) {
        print("attempting payload from mockusersettings with key: \(key)")
        if let data = archive[key] {
            callback(data as! [T])
        } else {
            print("Found nothing for: \(key)")
            callback(nil)
        }
    }

    public func encode<T>(key: String, payload: [T]) {
        print("Adding payload to mockusersettings with key: \(key)")
        archive[key] = payload as AnyObject
    }
}
```

and the test I'm trying to pass:

```
func testInitStorageWithCachedQuestions() {
    let expect = XCTestExpectation(description: "After init with cached questions, initStorage() should return a cached question.")

    let mockUserSettings = MockUserSettings()
    var questionsArray: [Question] = []
    for mockQuestion in mockResponse {
        if let question = Question(fromDict: mockQuestion) {
            questionsArray.append(question)
        }
    }
    mockUserSettings.encode(key: "questions", payload: questionsArray)
    mockUserSettings.encode(key: "currentIndex", payload: [0])
    mockUserSettings.encode(key: "nextFetchDate", payload: [Date.init().addingTimeInterval(+60)])

    let questionStore = QuestionStore(dateGenerator: Date.init, userSettings: mockUserSettings)

    questionStore.initStore() { (question) in
        let mockQuestionOne = Question(fromDict: self.mockResponse[0])
        XCTAssertTrue(question == mockQuestionOne)
        XCTAssert(self.numberOfNetworkCalls == 0)
        expect.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expect], timeout: 1.0)
}
```

If someone could help me wrap my head around what I''m doing wrong it would be much appreciated. Am I storing my mock objects properly? What is this ArrayBuffer and ArrayBridgeStorage thing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. My custom class was targeting both my app and tests. In the unit test, I was using the test target's version of my class constructor instead of the one for my main app.

So lesson to take away from this is just use `@testable import` and not to have your app classes target tests.